# Writing yaml file: attribute error

Tags: python, python-2.7, yaml

I'm trying to read a `yaml` file, replacing part of it and write the result it into the same file, but I get an attribute error.

**Code**

```
import yaml
import glob
import re
from yaml import load, dump
from yaml import CLoader as Loader, CDumper as Dumper
import io

list_paths = glob.glob("my_path/*.yaml")

for path in list_paths:    
    with open(path, 'r') as stream:
        try:
            text = load(stream, Loader=Loader)
            text = str(text)
            print text
            if "my_string" in text:
                start = "'my_string': '"
                end = "'"
                m = re.compile(r'%s.*?%s' % (start,end),re.S)
                m = m.search(text).group(0)
                text[m] = "'my_string': 'this is my string'"  
        except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
            print(exc)
    with io.open(path, 'w', encoding = 'utf8') as outfile:
        yaml.dump(text, path, default_flow_style=False, allow_unicode=True)
```

Error
I get this error for the `yaml_dump` line

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

**What I have tried so far**

- Not converting the text to a string, but then I get an error on the `m.search` line:

  TypeError: expected string or buffer
- Convert first to string and then to `dict`again, but I get this error from the code `text: dict(text)` : `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`

**Yaml file**

```
my string: something
string2: something else
```

**Expected result: yaml file**

```
my string: this is my string
string2: something else
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop getting that error all you need to do is change the

```
with io.open(path, 'w', encoding = 'utf8') as outfile:
    yaml.dump(text, path, default_flow_style=False, allow_unicode=True)
```

to

```
with open(path, 'w') as outfile:
    yaml.dump(text.encode("UTF-8"), outfile, default_flow_style=False, allow_unicode=True)
```

As the other answer says, this solution simply replaces the string `path` with the open file descriptor.

Comment: This allows me to rewrite the yaml file but since I'm writing from a string the result is this `"{my_string: this is my string, 'string2': 'something else'}". Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Thanks for changing the code. This is what I'm getting now: `'{country: this is the country field with annotations , ''something'': ''something''}'`

Comment: What did you want the output to be?

Comment: I needed it without curly braces and quotes. The solution I have found is to change the extension to .txt, modify the file and change the extension back to .yaml

Comment: What you are doing is converting your yaml object into a string then dumping that string.

Simply convert it back to a yaml object for it to work when you write it to file. 

i.e 
    `yamlData = load(text.encode("UTF-8"))`
    `yaml.dump(yamlData, outfile, default_flow_style=False, allow_unicode=True)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: No problem.  Happy too :D

Answer (score 1):

This

```
yaml.dump(text, path, default_flow_style=False, allow_unicode=True)
```

is not possible if `path` is a `str`. It must be an open file.